# Updating Airport Express Firmware

Tags: firmware, airport-express

I may be missing something painfully obvious, but how do I upgrade the firmware on an Airport Express? When I visit the [firmware page](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1471), I don't see a download link, but when I follow the attached instructions, the only firmware options I see in the Airport Utility are ones that I have downloaded locally. How do I go about upgrading this (either in Windows or Mac, I've got both).

Comment: If you bought it less than one year ago, call up 1-800-APL-CARE and talk to them.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I use the [AirPort Utility program](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airport-utility/id427276530?mt=8) to upgrade the firmware on all of my airport devices.

Here's some [FAQs from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1218) on the subject.  To quote:

> **How do I obtain and install a Wi-Fi base station firmware update?**
>
> - Open AirPort Utility (If there are no other important issues displayed, the base station in need of an update will be selected and the version information will be displayed).
> - Click Update Firmware.
> - Follow the prompts.
>
> *Important*: If you are updating a Time Capsule, disconnect any clients that may be using the Time Capsule's disk before installing the firmware.

Comment: I have the Airport Utility, but I don't see a link or button that says "Update Firmware". There's just a dropdown option for "Upload Firmware"

Comment: Click on your device in the left size of the window.  I think that on the right it will show the firmware and update will be one of the options.  Sorry, I'm not on my Airport to be more specific.

Comment: Clicking on the firmware version ("Version 6.3") leads to the same dialog as "Upload Firmware". The only options are older versions or to upload a new version if I can download it.

Comment: Huh.  And you have updated your OS software using Software Update?  What OS version are you on?

Comment: How about updating your Airport Utility.  I'm running Version 5.5.3 (553.20).  Open up the utility and then pull down the 'Airport Utility' menu to 'Check for updates'.

Comment: Yeah, it's on 5.5.3 on Windows and no need for an update. The Mac version can see the Airport Express just fine.

Comment: Huh.  Maybe you'll need to run Airport Utility from the Mac side with a Mac that is up-to-date or something.  Best of luck.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity I am adding this useful information in case others looking for the direct url to the firmware files (unavailable from apple's airport firmware download page as discovered by the OP) end up here.

Most/typical users should just use the airport utility (available on mac, windows, and ios) to update their airport router.

This page can explain how to manually download the firmware file itself from apple's servers and use the airport utility to manually update the device.

http://www.sallonoroff.co.uk/blog/2015/07/apple-airport-firmware-updates/

This page is the apple xml that contains the urls themselves (explained on the above page).

https://apsu.apple.com/version.xml

Comment: Consider quoting in addition to the references for the helpful content from the "link" if applicable.